# Adding multiple domains in active directory

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have installed Ad Domain services and created a root domain with dcpromo.exe. i would like to do 2 things now.

1. I would like to create child domains inside that root domain.
2. I would like to create a new domain along with root domain.

I got lot of indo about creating a child domain on google but when i open dcpromo.exe it doesn't show me "Advance Installation" option.

Comment: As MichelZ says, this is rarely a good idea. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create additional domain controllers. Each domain needs its own Domain Controller, you cannot create multiple domains using the same domain controller.

> I would like to create a new domain along with root domain.

This also requires a new domain controller. In addition, this can be configured as a new forest, or as a child domain with another name ("new domain tree root")

Also, keep in mind, that nowadays Microsoft recommends to not create child domains and stuff like that anymore, but to have one domain with several OU's as business units.

Comment: Hey Michel, Thanks for your help and suggestion. creating a new domain controller is fine but i ma not getting an advance option in dcpromo unitlity from which i can create a new domain. I am using windows server 2008 r2.Thanks. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787706%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Have a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731394(v=ws.10).aspx
Remember: You need a separate computer for this, you cannot do it on the same computer as you root domain controller. Each DC computer only controls/belongs to ONE domain.

Comment: i agree with you but i can always create child domain through dcpromo as shown in below in above comment link.

Comment: Interesting AD trivia: The AD design team originally thought to allow a single computer to host multiple Active Directories, which is one of the main reasons Sysvol uses a mess of junction points to this day, but the plan never panned out.

Comment: @RyanRies: You can actually do it with AD LDS / ADAM.

Comment: @user220550: No, it is not possible to do this on an exsting domain controller. Only on a new one.

Comment: so can i precreate a read only domain controller and created child domain ? if yes than i have already created a precreate read only controller and tried dcpromo but still it didn't showed me advance option to create a child domain.

Comment: A read only Domain Controller cannot be the only domain controller for a domain. You need a writeable controller. Also: What the heck are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: i have to work active directory users with my .net application and i have scenario to deal with multiple domains (child,new domain etc) so i want to setup this scenario. http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/creating-a-new-child-domain-in-windows-server-2008-r2#comment-25915

Comment: Setup 3x 2008 R2, install the AD DS role on all of them. DCPROMO on the first -> create root domain. DCPROMO on the second -> create child domain for existing domain. DCPROMO on the third -> create another domain

Comment: michael instead of that can i use another server machine on my network and use that machine domain in my ad and do development.If so than can you please guide me little procedure for that.thank you.

Comment: No, I will not guide you through the procedure. serverfault is not a tutorial site. Please read up by searching on google or by reading a book.

Comment: that's fine. i understand and your help has really given me a direction for resolution. i think i can create some virtual set up also for the same machine.Thanks Michael.

Comment: While this is old I feel it's important that anyone setting up a new Primary Domain do so with a physical computer instead of a VM, else they run the risk of getting locked out of their entire domain and messing up the internal clock of the PDC if one were to rollback the VM. However, as long as the hyper-visor doesn't need to communicate with any of it's Guest VMs it seems reasonable to make the second DC a VM. It always bothered me that a entire machine has to be dedicated as a Primary DC and I often have to remind myself of this truth.